# What is a person called who is playing an (online) game for another person as a paid service?

Tags: single-word-requests

Alice pays Bob to play using an online game account that Alice owns, so that Alice's account could level up or get stronger without Alice needing to play the game (grinding it).

What is Bob called?

Comment: This needs a little more clarity. What does "playing/grinding game" mean? Who is accepting payment, the player or the company running the game? Do you want a general term or one specific to this scenario?

Comment: A pays B to play game online account that A has, so that account could be level up or stronger without A to play/grinding it

Comment: You should edit the question to include all of the additional information, as comments can be deleted or moved to chat.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to (hopefully) make the question much clearer. As it was, it was quite difficult to parse. Let me know if I correctly understood your question and if my edit improves it.

Comment: yes , thank you very helpful

Comment: Some may hurl epithets while Alice might offer terms of endearment. You’ll need to be more specific about nuance and intent etc. The [tag:single-word-requests] tag information has some good advice about structuring such questions.

Comment: done , thank you

Comment: I'd say Bob is Alice's [***shill***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill)

Comment: In road racing (running), Bob would be called a "bib mule." If you want to coin a new term, you could try "avatar mule" or some such.

Comment: Sounds like a *mercenary*, a sort of paid soldier.

Answer (score 1):

This process is known as **power leveling**:

> Powerleveling is a service offered by some geeks who take your money away and play MMORPG day and night, working in two or three shifts. In a month or two they can buff your character to the highest level available — [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=powerleveling)

The term you want therefore is **power leveler**.